# Lagrangian equal to Hamiltonian - is it possible?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

In one calculation, I got a result where the Hamiltonian equals the Lagrangian, with both values constant.

Eventually I found the error and corrected it, but I began to wonder whether there could even be a physical system in which these values ​​are equal and constant.

Is such an arrangement even possible?
I think so, but it would have to have full spherical symmetry and perhaps other interesting properties.

Has anyone encountered such a solution or have an idea what system would have such a property?

Answer (score 3):

Lagrangian and Hamiltonian will be both numerically equal to kinetic energy (and to each other) whenever the potential energy is zero (everywhere).

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking, a hamiltonian and a lagrangian cannot be the same because the variables use to describe both are different. Only when the Hamiltonian is on-shell, i.e when the equations of motion are satisfied, this may be true.

One simple example is that of a free particle. The lagrangian is given by

$$ L = \frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2$$

It is straightforward to compute Hamiltonian which is given by

$$ H = \frac{p^2}{2m}$$

Note that a priori, there is no reason for $p = m\dot{x}$. This is enforced by classical equations of motion, mainly via

$$ \dot{x} = \frac{\partial{H}}{\partial{p}}$$

When you go into quantum regime or even statistical mechanics, it is useful to keep the momentum as an independent variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the Lagrangian function $\mathscr{L}$ and the Hamiltonian function $\mathcal{H}$ as the sum or the difference of the kinetic energy $K$ and the potential $U$, i.e.

$\mathscr{L} = K + U$

$\mathcal{H} = K - U$.

You can easily deduce that they're equal if $U = 0$.